# Cannot mock a new item using a fully reactive angular approch

Tags: angular, reactive-programming, rxjs-observables

This tool creates a metadata for authors. All of the instance variables are Observables using an Async pipe. I can edit and save the mock data, but when I create a new item, it does not get added to the mock Observable stream in a way where I can edit it. I can't tell if this is a limitation of using static data in a non-pipeable Observable or an implementation bug.

If it's a limitation of my mock, I can start on the backend, however if I'm coding the front end wrong, building a backend behind a broken UI will cause more problems.

The first button in the code (click)="create()" will add a new dummy story to the list,
but the child components do not receive the new object @Input() from the activeStory$.

storys.component.html (parent class)

```
<button class="btn btn-primary  my-2" (click)="create()">New Story</button>
 <div *ngIf="stories$ | async as stories">

 <ul class="list-group list-group-horizontal my-2">
  <li *ngFor="let story of stories" class="list-group-item nav-link link-primary" (click)="select(story.id)">{{story.title}}</li>

</ul>
   
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-8">
    <div *ngIf="activeStory$| async as story">

      <div *ngIf="!edit">
        <app-story-summary [story]="story" (editStory)="displayDetail()"></app-story-summary>
      </div>
      <div *ngIf="edit">
        <app-story [story]="story" (editEmitter)="hideDetail()" (storyEmitter)="saveStory($event)"></app-story>

    </div>

  </div>
```

storys.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-storys',
  templateUrl: './storys.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./storys.component.css']
})
export class StorysComponent {


  errorMessage = ""

  stories$ = this.backend.storiesWithAd$.pipe(
    catchError(err => {   //an arrow function followed by { implies a function
      this.errorMessage = err;    //to signify an object literal => ({ }) surround the braces with parens
      return EMPTY
    })
  );

  activeStory$: Observable<IStory> = combineLatest([
    this.backend.stories$,
    this.backend.selectedStoryIdAction$
  ]).pipe(
    map(([storys, selectedId]) =>
        storys.filter(story => story.id === selectedId)[0],
      tap(story => console.log("Active Story  and edit flag", story, this.edit))
    ));

  constructor(private backend: BackendService, private common: CommonService, private router: Router) {}

  edit = false;

  displayDetail(): void {
      this.router.navigate([{outlets: {details: ['story-details']}}]);
      this.edit = true;
  }
```

backend.service.ts

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class BackendService {
  private selectedStoryId = new BehaviorSubject<string>("0");
  private selectedPlotId = new BehaviorSubject<string>("0");
  selectedStoryIdAction$: Observable<string> = this.selectedStoryId.asObservable();
  selectedPlotIdAction$: Observable<string> = this.selectedPlotId.asObservable();

  private selectedSceneId = new BehaviorSubject<string>("0");
  private selectedPersonId = new BehaviorSubject<string>("0");
  selectedSceneIdAction$: Observable<string> = this.selectedSceneId.asObservable();
  selectedPersonIdAction$: Observable<string> = this.selectedPersonId.asObservable();

  private selectedEventId = new BehaviorSubject<string>("0");
  private selectedLocationId = new BehaviorSubject<string>("0");
  selectedEventIdAction$: Observable<string> = this.selectedEventId.asObservable();
  selectedLocationIdAction$: Observable<string> = this.selectedLocationId.asObservable();

  private selectedThingId = new BehaviorSubject<string>("0");
  selectedThingIdAction$: Observable<string> = this.selectedThingId.asObservable();

  //***********************  stub code to simulate an http call*********
  stories$: Observable<IStory[]> = of(testStorys);
  events$: Observable<IEvent[]> = of(testEvents);
  locations$: Observable<ILocation[]> = of(testLocations);
  plots$: Observable<IPlot[]> = of(testPlots);
  things$: Observable<IThing[]> = of(testThings);
  testPersons$: Observable<IPerson[]> = of(testPersons);
  selectedStory$: Observable<string> = this.selectedStoryIdAction$;
  scenes$: Observable<IScene[]> = of(testScenes);

//*********************************************************************

  private storyInsertSubject = new Subject<IStory>();
  storyInsertAction$ = this.storyInsertSubject.asObservable();

   storiesWithAd$ = merge(
      this.stories$,
      this.storyInsertAction$
    ).pipe(
      tap(s => console.log("Tap that stories wiht ad: ",s)),
      scan((acc, value) => (value instanceof Array) ?
        [...value] : [...acc, value], [] as IStory[]),
    );


  addStory(newStory?: IStory) {
    let astory = newStory || this.fakeStory();
    console.log("a dummy story ", astory);
    this.storyInsertSubject.next(astory);
    this.onSelected(astory.id);
  }

  

//not used in the mock  
constructor(private http: HttpClient, private common: CommonService) {
  }

  onSelected(storyId: string): void {
    this.selectedStoryId.next(storyId);
  }

  onPlotSelected(plotId: string): void {
    this.selectedPlotId.next(plotId);
  }


  onSceneSelected(sceneId: string): void {
    this.selectedSceneId.next(sceneId);
  }

  onPersonSelected(personId: string): void {
    this.selectedPersonId.next(personId);
  }

  onEventSelected(eventId: string): void {
    this.selectedEventId.next(eventId);
  }

  onLocationSelected(locationId: string): void {
    this.selectedLocationId.next(locationId);
  }

  onThingSelected(thingId: string): void {
    this.selectedThingId.next(thingId);
  }

  getStories(): Observable<IStory[]> {
    return this.stories$;
    // let url = this.endpoint+'/stories';
    // return this.http.post<IStory[]>(url,{cred:this.credential});
  }

  // private getCredentials():ICredentials{
  //   return this.common.credentials;
  // }

  save(collection: string, data: IStory): void {
    let url = this.endpoint + "/save/" + collection;
    this.http.post<IStory>(url, {payload: data});
  }

  fakeStory():IStory {
   let story_new = newStory;
    story_new.id = this.common.makeId(5);
    story_new.title = "a new story"
    story_new.userId = "12344asnwdbc";
    return story_new;
  }
```

**Theses two child components don't display when a new story is created**

(first child, shows summary view,no edits)
story-summary.component.ts

```
export class StorySummaryComponent {
  @Input() story:IStory|undefined;
  @Output() editStory:EventEmitter<void> = new EventEmitter<void>();

  constructor(private route:Router) { }

  showDetail():void {
    console.log("Clicked that display toggle")
    this.editStory.emit();
  }

}
```

story-summary.component.html

```
<div class="row my-2">

<div class="col-md-3">
  <label class="form-control ">Title: {{story.title}}</label>
  <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary my-2" (click)="showDetail()">Show Detail</button>

</div>

<div class="col-md-3">

  <label class="form-control">Author: {{story.author}}</label>
</div>

<div class="col-md-3">
  <label class="form-control">Genre: {{story.genre}}</label>

</div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6 my-3">

  <label class="form-control">Maguffin:{{story.maguffin}}</label>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6 my-3">

  <label class="form-control">Summary:{{story.summary}}</label>
</div>
```

(second child shows the edit view)
story.component.ts

```
export class StoryComponent {
  working = newStory;
  errorMessage="";
  @Input() story: IStory|undefined;
  @Output() storyEmitter: EventEmitter<IStory> = new EventEmitter<IStory>();
  @Output() editEmitter:EventEmitter<void> = new EventEmitter<void>();
  genre;

  constructor(private common: CommonService, private backend:BackendService) {
    this.genre = GENRE;
  }

  save(): void {
    let form = this.story;
    if(!form.id) {
      form.id = this.common.makeId(5);
    }
    this.storyEmitter.emit(form);
    this.working = newStory;
  }
  hideSummary():void{
    this.editEmitter.emit();
  }

}
```

story.component.html

```
<div class="col-md-12">
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary my-2" (click)="hideSummary()">Hide Detail</button>
  <div class="shading">
    <h3>{{story.title}}</h3>
  </div>
  <button type="button"
          class="btn btn-success" (click)="save()">Save
  </button>
  <div class="container">
    <form #form="ngForm">

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-5">
          <label for="title"
                 class="form-label">Title</label>
          <input
            #title="ngModel"
            required
            type="text"
            class="form-control"
            id="title"
            name="title"
            aria-describedby="titlehelp"
            [(ngModel)]="story.title"
            [class.field-error]="form.submitted && title.invalid">
          <div id="titlehelp"
               class="form-text">
            The name of your story.
          </div>
          <p [hidden]="title.valid || title.untouched" class="alert alert-danger">
            Enter a story name.
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-5">
          <label for="author"
                 class="form-label">Author</label>
          <input
            #author="ngModel"
            required
            type="text"
            class="form-control"
            id="author"
            name="author"
            [(ngModel)]="story.author"/>
        </div>

        <div class="mb-1 col-md-6">
          <div class="mb-1">
            <label for="maguffin"
                   class="form-label">Maguffin</label>
            <textarea
              #maguffin="ngModel"
              required
              type="text"
              class="form-control"
              id="maguffin"
              name="maguffin"
              aria-describedby="maguffinhelp"
              [(ngModel)]="story.maguffin"
              [class.field-error]="form.submitted && title.invalid"></textarea>
            <div id="maguffinhelp"
                 class="form-text">
              The hook for your reader.
            </div>
            <p [hidden]="maguffin.valid || maguffin.untouched" class="alert alert-danger">
              Enter a non-plot description.
            </p>
          </div>
 </div>
          <div class="row">


            <div class="col-md-4">

              <label class="form-label"
                     for="genres">Genre</label>
              <select #genres id="genres" name="genres" [(ngModel)]="story.genre" class="form-select">
                <option *ngFor="let val of genre" value="{{val.name}}">
                  {{val.name}} </option>
              </select>

            </div>



          <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="mb-1">
              <label for="title"
                     class="form-label">Summary</label>
              <textarea
                #summary="ngModel"
                required
                type="text"
                class="form-control"
                id="summary"
                name="summary"
                aria-describedby="sumhelp"
                [(ngModel)]="story.summary"
                [class.field-error]="form.submitted && summary.invalid"></textarea>
              <div id="sumhelp"
                   class="form-text">
                A high level plot description.
              </div>
              <p [hidden]="summary.valid || summary.untouched" class="alert alert-danger">
                Enter the a summary of the story plot.
              </p>
            </div>
             </div>

          </div>
        </div>



    </form>
  </div>

</div>
```